# How can I run a docker inside of a python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a docker container (A) that generates an output json file. I want to run this docker inside of my python code such that I can use the output file. As an example:

```
def read_output(self):
    Run_docker(A)
    with open(output) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Where the `output` is the address of the file that the container generated.
How can I implement `Run_docker(A)`?

Comment: The most simple approach would be to use the `subproccess` module and just run the desired `docker` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run("ubuntu:latest", "sleep infinity", detach=True)
```

Here's the [link](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) for details.

Also this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group)